# If $\text{Area} (A) = \text{Area} (B)$ and $\text{Perimeter}(A) = \text{Perimeter}(B) \implies A \cong B$?

Tags: geometry, area

If I have an $n$-gon $A$ and a **convex** $n$-gon $B$ with the same  perimeter and the same area, does $A\cong B$?

**Edit :** What becomes the answer if I replace convex by regular?

Comment: Nope, you can cut a $3\times 4$ rectangle along a diagonal, flip one of the peices and glue them back into a kite with same area and perimeter.

Comment: @IanMiller No; the gluing is back along the diagonal; that is to say, consider a rectangle with sides 3, 4, 3, 4, versus a kite quadrilateral with sides 3, 3, 4, 4.

Comment: If you replace "convex" by "regular", then all the relevant $n$-gons are similar, so it becomes trivial.

Comment: If you consider regular polygons (but allow $A$ and $B$ to have different numbers of sides), then it's true. The area of a regular $n$-gon is $A = \frac{1}{4\pi} P^2 f(\pi/n)$ for $f(t) = t \cot t$, and you can check that $f$ is decreasing on $[0,\pi/2]$.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Would you be able to elaborate your answer (Although it is trivial for some people, it isn't the case for other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The convex hexagon $A$ with vertices $(0,3),(2,2),(3,0),(2,-2),(-2,-2),(-2,2)$ and the convex hexagon $B$ with vertices $(0,3),(2,2),(2,-2),(0,-3),(-2,-2),(-2,2)$ are not congruent, although each has area $20$ and perimeter $8+4\sqrt5.$

Alternatively, consider the convex pentagon with vertices $(0,0),(-1,2),(0,5),(5,0),(2,-1)$ and the convex pentagon with vertices $(0,0),(-1,2),(0,5),(5,0),(3,-1).$

Comment: Maybe you could make a picture of this with labeled lengths? That would go really far.

Answer (score 0):

If they're both regular then just one of the given equalities is enough to show they're congruent.

---

For example, let's denote $a_1, a_2$ the edges of the two equal perimiter polygons, then we get $na_1=na_2$. Clearly $a_1=a_2$. Same goes for area.

Comment: Yes, this is an easy answer. However, they're not necessarly both regular in the question. One is regular and the other an arbitrary $n$-gon.